# Можно ли задать в метод с неопределённым количеством аргументов сразу множество аргументов например массив?

Tags: java

Можно ли задать в метод, с неопределённым количеством аргументов, сразу множество аргументов, например массив?

На сколько я знаю, возможность задавать в метод неопределённое количество аргументов, была реализована для того, чтобы не задавать все аргументы массивом. Осталась ли обратная совместимость?

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то можно перегрузить метод. Создать вариант с переменным числом параметров, и с каким-либо другим: `test(Type... args){} test(Type param1, Type param2){}`

Comment: Обратная совместимость с чем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я понял ваш вопрос так: "имея метод с переменным количеством аргументов, можно ли передать ему значения аргументов, не перечисляя их по одному в точке вызова, а указав только один аргумент - массив, содержащий все значения?"

Ответ - да, можно. Если у нас есть метод

```
void count(String... strings) {
    System.out.println(strings.length);
}
```

То следующие два вызова эквивалентны:

```
count("q", "w", "e"); // напечатает "3"

String[] args = {"q", "w", "e"};
count(args); // тоже напечатает "3"
```